# Template type in std::map

Tags: c++11, templates, std, std-pair

I want to create a vector of pairs. One of the pair members will be std::string and the second one templated type.

However this is giving me compilation error:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T> > arrayMembers;
```

Is this even possible? If som, how can I make it work?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: You are declaring a variable `arrayMembers`. This is only possible if you know its type at compile time, so a template declaration of a variable cannot work. Do you need to use arbitrary types in the vector? Then you may want to consider using a common base type or take a look at `std::any` / `boost::any`.

Comment: Variables templates are a C++17 feature, not a C++11 feature, and would mean that `arrayMembers<int>` and `arrayMembers<long>` are two completely distinct variables with different strings and values. Is that really what you're after?

Comment: Actually I want second member to be pointer to function

Comment: Do those functions all have the same signature? Then you may use `std::function` in place of `T`.

Comment: Nop, type of arguments may be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a template alias like so:

```
template<typename T>
using arrayMembers = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>;
```

Then you declare your actual variable like you would, for example, for a `std::vector`, like so:

```
arrayMembers<MyType> table;
```